# i want to sum up a field in array result in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

i have a query joining multiple tables together but i would love to sum u the amount fields in the collection together and push it to a view

```
$rec =DB::table('opos_itemdetails')
->join('opos_receiptproduct','opos_receiptproduct.id','=','opos_itemdetails.receiptproduct_id')
->join('product', 'product.id', '=', 'opos_receiptproduct.product_id')
->join('opos_receipt', 'opos_receipt.id', '=', 'opos_receiptproduct.receipt_id')
->join('opos_terminal', 'opos_terminal.id', '=', 'opos_receipt.terminal_id')
->join('location', 'location.id', '=', 'opos_terminal.id')
->get();
```

Comment: What all fields you need to sum up?

Comment: I want to sum up the amount field from the result produced from this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$rec =DB::table('opos_itemdetails')
->join('opos_receiptproduct','opos_receiptproduct.id','=','opos_itemdetails.receiptproduct_id')
->join('product', 'product.id', '=', 'opos_receiptproduct.product_id')
->join('opos_receipt', 'opos_receipt.id', '=', 'opos_receiptproduct.receipt_id')
->join('opos_terminal', 'opos_terminal.id', '=', 'opos_receipt.terminal_id')
->join('location', 'location.id', '=', 'opos_terminal.id')
->sum('table_name.column_name');
```